# converting from wav audio file to pcm audio file using ffmpeg javascript

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg but as javascript not php.I want to convert from wav file to pcm.the conversion to mp3 or wma is working fine but not to pcm it's telling me that at least one input must be selected what is the error?here is my code(command lines only):

```
var arguments = [];
    arguments.push("-y");
    arguments.push("-vn");
    arguments.push("-i");
    arguments.push(fileName);

    arguments.push("-b:a");
    arguments.push(getBitrate());

    switch (getOutFormat()) {
    case "mp3":
        arguments.push("-acodec");
        arguments.push("libmp3lame");
        arguments.push("out.mp3");
        break;
    case "wma":
        arguments.push("-acodec");
        arguments.push("wmav1");
        arguments.push("out.asf");
        break;
    case "pcm":
        //arguments.push("s16le");
        arguments.push("-ac");
        arguments.push("1");
        arguments.push("-f");

        //arguments.push("pcm_s16le");
        arguments.push("out.pcm");
    }
```

Comment: even without the use of ffmpeg simple javascript conversion could do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mp3 and wma are file formats (or wrappers), pcm is a codec.
I would think that ffmpeg does not support pcm as an output format, although it does support pcm as an output codec.
What is your goal ?

edit : check

```
$ ffmpeg -formats
```

and

```
$ ffmpeg -codecs
```

for more info on supported formats and codecs.
args edited with the help from stackoverflow.com/questions/4854513/can-ffmpeg-convert-audio-to-raw-pcm-if-so-how

You might get a raw pcm output with :

```
case "pcm":
        arguments.push("-f");
        arguments.push("s16le");
        arguments.push("-acodec");
        arguments.push("pcm_s16le");
        arguments.push("-ac");
        arguments.push("1");
        arguments.push("out.pcm");
```

Be aware that what you are producing is usually called a *raw* file and that you will need to specify sampling frequency, quantization, number of channels, endianess to be able to read it.

Comment: doesn't the `-f` option need an argument ? It is supposed to be the output format. Here it looks like ffmpeg will interpret the output filename as an (unknown) output format.

Comment: At least one output file must be specified.still gives error.if I removed the -f it says that output/out.pcm is invalid argument.what is going wrong please help??